# When you split a node from a B-Tree and it's of an odd order, how do you evenly distribute the keys?

Tags: java, key, b-tree

When you split a node that is of order 5, then you would have 4 keys, so you would be able to distribute evenly, but when the node has an odd number of keys then things dont distribute so evenly. Any help with this?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you should add the homework tag.

Answer (score 2):

Go read Wikipedia article.  It describes this exactly:

> If this number is odd, then U=2L and one of the new nodes contains (U−2)/2 = L−1 elements, and hence is a legal node, and the other contains one more element, and hence it is legal too. If U−1 is even, then U=2L−1, so there are 2L−2 elements in the node. Half of this number is L−1, which is the minimum number of elements allowed per node.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree